# Detecting round shapes among contours

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, trackball

I have a code, which gives me a lot of contours suspected to be a ball,
In order to minimize the list and find the real ball among them,
I have used a couple of classifiers.
First Circularity, I use a formula which shows how round are the contours,
The roundest are chosen for the next step.
Next we compare an Image of a real ball to the ball we are searching for in the image. This is enough almost 85% of the time , yet for our needs we need something even better.
Are there any other good classifiers? 
we are using opencv on c++

Comment: Does the area of the ball differ between the test image and the original one?

Comment: The area does differ,I only compare the average color of contour and the ball ,The pic of the ball is very zoomed in and the area cannot be used therfore

Comment: Can you add a sample image?

Comment: please provide an example image. did you try hough transform to find the round ball right away? I guess you have some preknowledge about the diameter.

Comment: how "good" are your contours? you should post input images and intermediate (contour) images